# XEN cannot start domains after upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: xen

Dom0 wrong

```
xl list 
Name                                        ID   Mem VCPUs      State   Time(s)
(null)                                       0 31898     8     r-----      27.7
```

starting of domains end with error

```
xl create xen/xxx.cfg
Parsing config from xen/xxx.cfg
libxl: error: libxl_domain.c:1214:libxl__get_domid: failed to get own domid (domid)
libxl: error: libxl_device.c:1167:device_hotplug: Domain 4:Failed to get domid
libxl: error: libxl_domain.c:1214:libxl__get_domid: failed to get own domid (domid)
libxl: error: libxl_device.c:1167:device_hotplug: Domain 4:Failed to get domid
libxl: error: libxl_create.c:1299:domcreate_launch_dm: Domain 4:unable to add disk devices
libxl: error: libxl_domain.c:1214:libxl__get_domid: failed to get own domid (domid)
libxl: error: libxl_device.c:968:libxl__initiate_device_generic_remove: Domain 4:unable to get my domid
libxl: error: libxl_domain.c:1214:libxl__get_domid: failed to get own domid (domid)
libxl: error: libxl_domain.c:1214:libxl__get_domid: failed to get own domid (domid)
libxl: error: libxl_device.c:968:libxl__initiate_device_generic_remove: Domain 4:unable to get my domid
libxl: error: libxl_domain.c:1214:libxl__get_domid: failed to get own domid (domid)
libxl: error: libxl_domain.c:1107:devices_destroy_cb: Domain 4:libxl__devices_destroy failed
libxl: error: libxl_domain.c:1034:libxl__destroy_domid: Domain 4:Non-existant domain
libxl: error: libxl_domain.c:993:domain_destroy_callback: Domain 4:Unable to destroy guest
libxl: error: libxl_domain.c:920:domain_destroy_cb: Domain 4:Destruction of domain failed
```

Answer (score 3):

This wasn't enough for me, my XEN service wasn't starting correctly and it was a conflict with QEMU. I haven't managed to work neither on Ubuntu 20.04 nor 20.04.1. I had to upgrade to **Ubuntu 20.10**.

1. Back up all the XEN configuration under `/etc/xen/`
2. Uninstall XEN and QEMU:

```
apt purge xen-system-amd64 xen-hypervisor-common xen-hypervisor-4.9-amd64 xen-hypervisor-4.11-amd64 xenstore-utils xen-utils-common xen-tools xe-guest-utilities  libxen-dev qemu-system qemu-system-common qemu-block-extra qemu-efi-aarch64 qemu-efi-arm qemu-slof qemu-system qemu-system-arm qemu-system-common qemu-system-data qemu-system-gui qemu-system-mips qemu-system-misc qemu-system-ppc qemu-system-s390x qemu-system-sparc qemu-system-x86 qemu-user qemu-user-binfmt qemu-utils
apt autoremove
```

3. Upgrade to Ubuntu 20.10

Edit `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and set `Prompt=normal` in order to upgrade to latest version (non LTS).

```
do-release-upgrade
```

4. Install just the XEN hypervisor on Ubuntu 20.10

```
apt install xen-hypervisor
```

5. Restore the XEN configuration
6. Reboot

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by saving the guest configurations (/etc/xen/*cfg) and uninstalling all xen components

```
apt search xen
apt purge <all components installed or partial config conponents>
```

and then reinstalling

```
apt install xen-hypervisor
```

and then restore the cfg files.

Answer (score 1):

for me uninstalling and the reinstalling the xen-hypervisor package was enough to fix the problem. Also note that some .cfg files may contain a path to v4.9 of pygrub, which is now at version v4.11 in Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

I found another source of the problem.  There are save files in **/var/lib/xen**, comprising some json description files, and often a memory dump in the **save** subdirectory.  Those may be in the Xen 4.9 format, and cause problems which show up as **(null)** for the dom0 name.  I removed the json files and the saves; xl started working again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case on Ubuntu 20.04, when you run:

```
grep xen /var/log/syslog
```

You got error message saying "No space left on device".

When you check the partition where /var/lib/xen resides, on my machine it showed that it was 100% full. After cleaning up the disk space (in my case, there was terabytes of old docker images), running

```
systemctl restart xen.service
```

fixed the issue.