# Unable to add disk devices for domU after kernel update 5.4.0-67

Tags: 20.04, kernel, xen

Running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS with xen 4.11

After the last kernel update 5.4.0-67 and a server restart none of the guests were started. Trying to start a domU manually I got the following error message:

```
libxl: error: libxl_device.c:1130:device_backend_callback: Domain 8:unable to add device with path /local/domain/0/backend/vbd/8/51712
libxl: error: libxl_create.c:1299:domcreate_launch_dm: Domain 8:unable to add disk devices
libxl: error: libxl_device.c:1130:device_backend_callback: Domain 8:unable to remove device with path /local/domain/0/backend/vbd/8/51712
libxl: error: libxl_domain.c:1107:devices_destroy_cb: Domain 8:libxl__devices_destroy failed
libxl: error: libxl_domain.c:1034:libxl__destroy_domid: Domain 8:Non-existant domain
libxl: error: libxl_domain.c:993:domain_destroy_callback: Domain 8:Unable to destroy guest
libxl: error: libxl_domain.c:920:domain_destroy_cb: Domain 8:Destruction of domain failed
```

Only reverting to the previous kernel 5.4.0-66 solved the problem.

Is it a bug in the kernel or did I miss something in my configuration?

Comment: I am also suffering from the same issue. I booted into the previous kernel and the Xen DomU VMs were able to be started again. I've been researching for a few days now and I can't find any real answers to this yet. I have even tried forcing a re-install of Xen on Ubuntu however same issue. Next option is to create a new Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS server and install Xen to see if the same issue occurs.

Comment: I've performed a full fresh install of Ubuntu.20.04.2 LTS and installed Xen from the Ubuntu repository.  The default kernel is 5.4.0-67.  The issue creating DomU still exists.  The exact same config on another server under 5.4.0-66 kernel works fine, moving to the 5.4.0-67 kernel on the other server cause disk errors. 
Error Messages:
root@server:/xen-vms/active# xl create ubuntu01.cfg
Parsing config from ubuntu01.cfg
libxl: error: libxl_create.c:589:libxl__domain_make: domain creation fail: Invalid argument
libxl: error: libxl_create.c:964:initiate_domain_create: cannot make domain: -3

Comment: Same here on 5.4.0-67 with 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa). `unable to add disk devices` can not start the vms.
```
libxl: error: libxl_device.c:1130:device_backend_callback: Domain 4:unable to add device with path /local/domain/0/backend/vbd/4/51712
```

Comment: There are comments in this related topic (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239384/xen-cannot-start-domains-after-upgrading-from-18-04-to-20-04) that suggests an upgrade to ubuntu 20.10 solved the issue (however I need to continue to run the LTS version).  Ubuntu 20.10 uses Xen 4.11.4, Ubuntu 20.04LTS uses Xen 4.11.3.  I also found this (https://blog.werk21.de/en/2018/02/08/build-xen-hypervisor-414-and-xen-tools-ubuntu-1804-or-2004-pvh) which walks through upgrading to xen 4.14 on Ubuntu 18.04.  Would be better if we can fix Xen 4.11.3 on Ubuntu 20.04.2 rather than upgrade all of Xen.

Comment: There is a bug report related to our problem:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xen/+bug/1920202

Comment: I have run #>apt install linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04 on my test server and can confirm that the Xen DomU servers now start using the 5.8 Kernel.  It doesn't fix the defect in the 5.4.0-67 LTS Kernel but it is a good way to resolve the issue and upgrade to the latest Kernel as well if you are happy to go down that path.  Updating the Hardware stack is also supported to April 2025 - so all good
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal
Linux xen03 5.8.0-45-generic #51~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 23 13:46:31 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 2):

This is an incomplete patch (only 1 of 2 commits) for xen in Kernel 5.4.0-67. This is a problem with the kernel, not the xen system.

Just boot 5.4.0-66 and wait for kernel update by Ubuntu.
The missing patch is proposed for 5.4.0-71 (see [kernel.ubuntu.com](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-focal.git/commit/?h=Ubuntu-5.4.0-71.79&id=b6c0a7f33687639b59ce52882cf35e95e5f5454a))

On 20.04 you can switch to the HWE-Kernel. For kernel 5.8 both commits are proposed for 5.8.0-49.55 (see [kernel.ubuntu.com](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-groovy.git/commit/?h=Ubuntu-5.8.0-49.55&id=c4bc751564d85cfd846c1000f8ed7ed29c40a9c5))

See our bug report [lp#1920660](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1920660)

Best regards, Kelly.

Answer (score 0):

What also solves the issue is upgrading to the new hwe-stack

```
sudo apt install linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04
```

This installs a 5.8 kernel not having this issue.

Comment: Not for me :(
One of my DomU is OPNsense based on freebsd and it isn't working with the 5.8 kernel. It starts but there is no connection to the domU via IP address. Something with the interfaces (WAN as pci passthrough and others as bridges) seems to be wrong.

Comment: Interesting. For testing purposes I have an OPNsense DomU as well and it's running (v20.7) with the 5.8k

Comment: Do you use bridge interfaces or pci passthrough?

Answer (score 0):

@yosamite , I have a Dell OptiPlex 9010, and at some point when Xorg was updated, any kernel > 5.4 (e.g., 5.8) causes the (i915) video to become very slow (for example, it takes about 1/4 second for Firefox to draw its file menu, and when moving the mouse up and down the menu, the highlight takes about 1/4 second to update completely, with horizontal lines until it finishes redrawing).  I guess I will have to wait for the -71 kernel.

When not under Xen, these kernels are fine, but under Xen as a Dom0, graphics are slow.